# Прописная буква

Tags: прописная-строчная

Реализация приоритетов бюджетной политики, сформулированной в Указах Президента РФ. Правильно ли написаны прописные буквы? Спасибо.

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Гм… Текст у Вас, думаю, неофициальный. А потому...

См. http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=90#pp90 :

> **§ 196.** Названия должностей, званий, титулов пишутся со строчной
>   буквы, напр.: *президент...*
>
> В официальных текстах названия высших
>   государственных должностей и титулов
>   пишутся с прописной буквы, напр.:
>   *Президент Российской Федерации...* Однако в неофициальных текстах эти
>   названия пишутся со строчной буквы,
>   напр.: *выборы президента, выступление
>   председателя Госдумы, распоряжение
>   премьер-министра, приём у королевы.*

То же по поводу неофициальных текстов и в ответе Грамоты.ру:

[image]

Но на практике обычно **президента** предпочитают писать с прописной. См. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B2+%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%A0%D0%A4%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22%D0%B2+%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%A0%D0%A4%22&tbm=bks&start=0

И потому, думаю, лучше сделать так:

*Реализация приоритетов бюджетной политики, сформулированной **в указах Президента РФ.***

Comment: спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Слава, в примере речь идет об указах как о документе, а не о нарицательном существительном. Поэтому, согласно правилам, слово "указ" в этом примере надо писать с прописной. См. здесь:[Прописная или строчная](http://acentrum.ru/Content/russkij-yazik-i-stilj-sudebnih-dokumentov/18)

Comment: Не согласен. В данном случае речь идёт не о каком-то "сборнике" "Указов на тему", а о целом ряде документов, имеющих общую направленность.

Comment: [Подходы к планированию бюджетных ассигнований и основные приоритеты бюджетных расходов](http://zlat-go.ru/07_financial_management/district_budget/the_basic_directions_of_budgetary_policy/). Здесь имеется в виду документ, содержащий указы, а не какие-то отдельные указы.

Comment: Вы внимательно прочитали вопрос?
По Вашей ссылке - документ, не имеющий **никакого** отношения ни к президенту, ни к его указам. А в вопросе речь идёт об отсылке к **нескольким** указам (точное число не называется), которые, так или иначе, следует учитывать при составлении бюджета.